# SQL MAX SELECT COUNT Quetion

Tags: sql, select, count

The data base like

```
id    order_no
1     O1    
1     O2
2     O3
2     O4
3     O5
```

and i want to find the person who order most
the answer should be like

```
id    max(count)
1     2
2     2
```

and this is my SQL

```
select order_user, MAX(times)
from (select order_user, count(order_user) AS times
      from labt04
      group by order_user);
```

but it alert not a single group function
does anyone know how to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to get what you want:

```
WITH my_cte (my_id, times)
AS
(
    SELECT      my_id, COUNT(*)
    FROM        labt04
    GROUP BY    my_id
)
SELECT      my_id, times
FROM        my_cte
WHERE       times = (SELECT MAX(times) FROM my_cte)
```

Comment: Oracle, Postgres, and even SQLite support CTE as well.  If Gordon's answer works then so would yours most likely.

Answer (score 3):

In ANSI standard SQL, you would use `rank()`:

```
select order_user, times
from (select order_user, count(*) AS times,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from labt04
      group by order_user
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `CTE + ROW_NUMBER() + MAX()` statements in SQL like below:

It will be faster then `top clause`

```
;WITH Order_CTE_Row_Number_By_Id
AS
(
    SELECT      id, 
                Row_NUmber() over (Partition by id order by id) AS rowNumber_Id,
                order_no
    FROM        labt04
),
Order_CTE_Max_By_rowNumberById
AS
(
    SELECT      id, 
                Max(rowNumber_Id) over (order by rowNumber_Id desc) AS maxNumber_RowNumber_Id,
                rowNumber_Id,
                order_no
    FROM        Order_CTE_Row_Number_By_Id
)
SELECT  id, maxNumber_RowNumber_Id AS 'max(count)'
FROM    Order_CTE_Max_By_rowNumberById
WHERE   rowNumber_Id = maxNumber_RowNumber_Id
```